# Remove decimal points with Stream() instead of using for loop

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am trying to remove the decimal points from the elements of a list without using a for loop. Could 
 you please point out a declarative approach?

```
List<BigDecimal> numbers = Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal(1.2), new BigDecimal(2.2));
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    BigDecimal number = numbers.get(i);
    numbers.set(i, number.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
}
```

Comment: `numbers.replaceAll(number -> number.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR));`

Comment: @Holger post it as an answer. This is the perfect answer.

Comment: This answer is actually quite nice, thanks @Holger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
List<BigDecimal> numbers = Stream.of(new BigDecimal(1.2), new BigDecimal(2.2))
    .map(n -> n.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Besides, why not simply:

```
Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal(1.2).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR, new BigDecimal(2.2).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do as below,

```
Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal(1.2), new BigDecimal(2.2)).stream()
        .map(num->num.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It's the same as I proposed instead of yours creates an unnecessary, intermediate `List`

Comment: @Andronicus I saw it after my screen refresh. Anyway, yours is better